# Why is the compiler generating a push/pop instruction pair?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, sse

I compiled the code below with the VC++ 2010 compiler:

```
__declspec(dllexport)
unsigned int __cdecl __mm_getcsr(void) { return _mm_getcsr(); }
```

and the generated code was:

```
push ECX
    stmxcsr [ESP]
    mov EAX, [ESP]
pop ECX
retn
```

Why is there a `push ECX`/`pop ECX` instruction pair?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The compiler is making room on the stack to store the MXCSR. It could have equally well done this:

```
sub esp,4
stmxcsr [ESP]
mov EAX, [ESP]
add esp,4
retn
```

But "push ecx" is probably shorter or faster.

Comment: D'oh... totally missed that. :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: And how does that explain the pop?

Comment: @CodeInChaos - the `pop` restores the stack pointer, just as `add esp,4` would.

Comment: but wouldn't `pop EAX` instead of `mov EAX, [ESP]; pop ECX` be even better?

Answer (score 3):

The push here is used to allocate 4 bytes of temporary space. `[ESP]` would normally point to the pushed return address, which we cannot overwrite.

`ECX` will be overwritten here, however, `ECX` is a probably a volatile register in the ABI you're targeting, so functions don't have to preserve `ECX`.

The reason a push/pop is used here is a space (and possibly speed) optimization.

Answer (score 0):

It creates an top-of-stack entry that ESP now refers to as the target for the stmxcsr instruction.  Then the result is stored in EAX for the return.